# Does GitHub have built-in support for submodules?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I am trying to look for a feature that allows me to add submodules to one of my modules, but I can't seem to find it on the GitHub website. Is this something that I'll have to use the Git shell for?

Comment: The github web interface does support clickable links if you push a repo that contains a submodule, see e.g. here: https://github.com/themanaworld/tmwa/tree/master/deps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has "built in" support for submodules, github is just a visual GUI for the git protocol, which is not made or owned by "GitHub"

If their GUI doesn't provide for some kind of drag-and-drop way to link a submodule, then you have to use the command line or a different GUI to do it. Once the submodule is set up , however you do it, github will be able to show it to you

Comment: Is it possible to create a submodule directly with just the GitHub website though?

Comment: @JohnH, you cannot add a submodule using GitHub's web UI. That interface is a bare-bones afterthought. It only provides a tiny subset of the functionality that GitHub supports, and should only be used when you have no other option. Instead, use a proper Git client like the `git` CLI tool, a decent GUI tool like SourceTree or, if you absolutely must, GitHub's GUI client.