# github limited access to project folders

Tags: github

I have a github repository with few folders in it. What I would like to achieve is that I want to provide access to shared users to only particular folders. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a Git submodule might give you what you want here.  Submodules behave like repositories which effectively live inside of another repository.  You could place the shared code into a submodule and then only grant permission to this section of the parent repo for shared users.  Your shared users would not have permission to the outer parent repo.

Have a look here for more information: [Does GitHub have built-in support for submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035460/does-github-have-built-in-support-for-submodules)